# iPad allow other applications to import documents to my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm building an iPad app that allows users to save files in it and I want users to be able to open and import documents from other applications to my application. For example, I know that if you received an email and you want to save the attachment to my application, you're able to click on it and "Open with..." and choose the application you want to import the file to.

I think this may be like a global registry where you can set to allow for other applications to see what files your app can take and thus import to your app, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Please let me know if you know how to do this.

Thanks,
-David

Answer (score 3):

This is a new feature that was introduced in iPhone OS 3.2 (for iPad), it is called [Document Support](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS3_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009337-SW8).